# How to make JScrollPane not hide JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

My problem is that `JScrollPane` is not showing a `JTable` inside it. When I initialize a table without `JScrollPane` everything works perfectly.

How to make `JScrollPane` not hide `JTable`?

```
private void initComponents() {
    setLayout(new GroupLayout());
    add(getJComboBox0(), new Constraints(new Leading(24, 284, 12, 12), new Leading(45, 10, 10)));
    add(getJLabel0(), new Constraints(new Leading(24, 12, 12), new Leading(17, 12, 12)));
    add(getJButton1(), new Constraints(new Leading(320, 12, 12), new Leading(86, 10, 10)));
    add(getJButton0(), new Constraints(new Leading(320, 126, 12, 12), new Leading(45, 12, 12)));
    add(getJScrollPane1(), new Constraints(new Leading(25, 282, 12, 12), new Bilateral(82, 12, 26, 403)));
    setSize(1200, 650);
}

private JScrollPane getJScrollPane1() {
    if (jScrollPane1 == null) {

        jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane();
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(getJTable1());
    }
    return jScrollPane1;
}

private JTable getJTable1() {
    if (testCaseTable == null) {
        ProjectTableModel ptm =new ProjectTableModel();
        testCaseTable = new JTable();
        testCaseTable.setModel(ptm);


    }
    return testCaseTable;
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Care to share your code?

Comment: By copy-pasting the code in the [official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#show)

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to answer without seeing your code, but make sure you're adding the `JScrollPane` to your `JFrame`, not the `JTable`.

So for a table without scrolling you do this...

```
add(myTable);
```

and to add scrolling you do this...

```
add(new JScrollPane(myTable));
```

Now that I can see your code, I would change this line...

```
jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane();
jScrollPane1.setViewportView(getJTable1());
```

To simply be this...

```
jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(getJTable1());
```

Also, as pointed out by @alain, the following line shouldn't compile...

```
setLayout(new GroupLayout());
```

So why don't you change it to this, and then give it a try...

```
setLayout(new GroupLayout(this));
```

Comment: So what exactly is happening? Are you seeing the scrollbars appear, or nothing at all? And how are you displaying your JFrame - are you calling `pack()` and `setVisible(true)` somewhere after you call `initComponents()`?

Comment: I have none - that's not a problem with table model. Point is that even that table gets drawn correctly but it's not shown in the scrollpane. If I initialize table without jscrollpane everything works just fine. The only problem is I may have to scroll this table so the problem is only partially solved.

Answer (score 1):

The code you provide doesn't compile :

```
setLayout(new GroupLayout());
```

There is no empty constructor for [class GroupLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/GroupLayout.html#constructor_summary).

What about replacing that with :

```
setLayout(new GridLayout());
```

Comment: How about changing it to `setLayout(new GroupLayout(this));`? The point @alain is trying to make is that your code shouldn't even be compiling. Refer to the Java API docs at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/GroupLayout.html to see how GroupLayout should be used.

Comment: @Swemack Can you give us the real code because you obvioulsy don't use what you've pasted, or your not using a Swing component...